# Collapsing toolbar layout doesn't scroll smoothly

Tags: android

I'm using the next code to make an collpasing toolbar that displays an image, and then collapse the toolbar when the user scrolls down:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_cover"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
            app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.SubtitleText" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_commerce" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_promotions_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

The problem is that the collapsing toolbar does not scroll smoothly. the rest of the layout scrolls just fine when the toolbar It is entirely collapsed, but if the toolbar is not entirely collapsed, the scroll movement is unnatural. The "content_commerce.xml" layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Presentation-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/content_commerce_presentation"/>

        <!--Description-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/content_commerce_description"/>

        <!--Entrys - categories-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/content_commerce_entries_categories"/>

        <!--Payment Methods-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/content_commerce_payment_methods"/>

        <!--Additional Information-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/content_commerce_additional_information"/>

        <!--Contact Information-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/content_commerce_contact"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The rest of layouts don't contain any scrollable view, only LinearLayouts, TextViews and ImageViews.

Comment: Please show your full xml layout, along with the "content_commerce" layout.

Comment: did you solved your issue